# Need Assistance With a Powershell Script to Move a Computer Object in Active Directory to New OU As Soon as the Computer Object Gets Created in AD

Tags: powershell, powercli

I have a script that deploys a new VM in my VMware environment. As soon as the computer object lands in the default "Computers" OU in Active Directory, I would like to have the script move the computer object to a different OU immediately. Trying to time this with a sleep is difficult because the time to build the VM varies each time the script is ran and other tasks that need to run won't perform their job successfully unless the computer object is moved out of the default "Computers" OU to a different specified OU immediately. Any thoughts of how to accomplish this would be much appreciated!

Comment: Do you only do one at a time? You can do a `do-until` loop with an if condition to see when the object is there, and have it move the object to it's corresponding ou.

Comment: We do something similar where I work. From a server we have a scheduled task running on a 5 minute  interval executing a powershell script that's moving all computer objects that meet specific naming criteria from one OU to another.

Comment: Abraham, Thank you for this information! The script has a for each loop in it to create the VMs, so it depends on how many the user selects to create on each run as it can vary. With that being the case, can you provide an example of what the do-until loop would look like for this? I am especially struggling with the syntax on how to hold on proceeding in the script until it sees the computer object created in AD and then moves it from the default computers OU to a different OU. Could someone please kindly help me out with an example?

Comment: write-host "************ Creating $ServerName; DO NOT CLOSE/STOP THIS SCRIPT! ************`n`n" -f yellow
 do {
  Get-ADComputer -identity $servername -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue
  write-host "." -nonewline -f red
  sleep 3
 } until(Get-ADComputer -identity $servername -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue -warningaction silentlycontinue)
 $serverdn = (Get-ADComputer -identity $servername).distinguishedname
 Move-ADObject -identity "$serverdn" -TargetPath "$fullpath"

Comment: I tried the above and unfortunately it didn't work for what I need it to do. It didn't wait until the computer object existed. it just said it didn't exist and then bombed.

Comment: Unfortunately this recommendation below did not work. It fails right away when checking for the computer object. I basically need something that keeps trying to see if the computer object exists and if it doesn't exists it keeps waiting until the object does exist and then as soon as the object exists, it moves it to the new OU. Any code suggestions would be much appreciated!

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

You can try with do-until:

```
write-host "************ Creating $ServerName; DO NOT CLOSE/STOP THIS SCRIPT! ************nn" -f yellow 
do { 
    write-host "." -nonewline -f red 
    Start-Sleep 3
    } 
until(Get-ADComputer -identity $servername -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue) 
$serverdn = (Get-ADComputer -identity $servername).distinguishedname 
Move-ADObject -identity $serverdn -TargetPath $fullpath
```

You can also try to [pre-stage](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/windows/it-pro/windows-server-2008-R2-and-2008/cc754469(v=ws.11)) your computer account in the correct OU, before joining the server to the domain

Comment: Unfortunately this did not work. It fails right away when checking for the computer object. I basically need something that keeps trying to see if the computer object exists and if it doesn't exists it keeps waiting until the object does exist and then as soon as the object exists, it moves it to the new OU.

Comment: you can try with this code: https://pastebin.com/vw7NjdVz
it set a "flag" and if the flag is "raised to 1", then it needs to continue until flag is lower to 0